# Reading data form multiple csv file and writing it into one csv file using Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, spring-batch

I am trying to read data from multiple csv file present in resources/input/user_*.csv
and writing in one csv file present in resources/output/user.csv

Below is my Config File

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Value(value = "classpath:input/user_*.csv")
    private Resource[] resources;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<User> flatFileItemReader(){
        log.info("flatFileItemReader execution started");
        FlatFileItemReader<User> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setName("ReadMultipleCsv");
        reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        log.info("flatFileItemReader execution completed");
        return reader;
    }

    private LineMapper<User> lineMapper(){
        DefaultLineMapper<User> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);
        lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"id","name","department","salary"});

        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<User> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(User.class);

        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
        return lineMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public MultiResourceItemReader<User> multiResourceItemReader(){
        log.info("multiResourceItemReader() execution started");
        MultiResourceItemReader<User> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
        reader.setResources(resources);
        reader.setDelegate(flatFileItemReader());
        log.info("multiResourceItemReader() execution completed");
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer(){
        log.info("writer() execution started");
        FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        writer.setResource(new ClassPathResource("output/user.csv"));
        writer.setAppendAllowed(true);

        DelimitedLineAggregator<User> delimitedLineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
        delimitedLineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<User> beanWrapperFieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        beanWrapperFieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] {"id","name","department","salary"});
        delimitedLineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(beanWrapperFieldExtractor);
        writer.setLineAggregator(delimitedLineAggregator);
        log.info("writer() execution completed");
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step(){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("get-student").<User, User>chunk(5)
                .reader(multiResourceItemReader())
                .writer(writer()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(){
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("process-student").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step()).end().build();
    }
}
```

And this is my user entity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String department;
    private String salary;
}
```

logs =>

```
2022-08-22 16:40:06.295  INFO 17264 --- [           main] c.s.SpringBatchMultipleCsvToApplication  : Starting SpringBatchMultipleCsvToApplication using Java 1.8.0_121 on GBMLVVCSW3823 with PID 17264 (C:\Users\NavghS\Downloads\spring-batch-multiple-csv-to\spring-batch-multiple-csv-to\target\classes started by NavghS in C:\Users\NavghS\Downloads\spring-batch-multiple-csv-to\spring-batch-multiple-csv-to)

2022-08-22 16:40:06.300  INFO 17264 --- [           main] c.s.SpringBatchMultipleCsvToApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"

2022-08-22 16:40:08.999  INFO 17264 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)

2022-08-22 16:40:09.017  INFO 17264 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]

2022-08-22 16:40:09.018  INFO 17264 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]

2022-08-22 16:40:09.349  INFO 17264 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext

2022-08-22 16:40:09.350  INFO 17264 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2936 ms

2022-08-22 16:40:09.542  INFO 17264 --- [           main] com.shrikant.config.BatchConfig          : flatFileItemReader execution started

2022-08-22 16:40:09.554  INFO 17264 --- [           main] com.shrikant.config.BatchConfig          : flatFileItemReader execution completed

2022-08-22 16:40:09.559  INFO 17264 --- [           main] com.shrikant.config.BatchConfig          : multiResourceItemReader() execution started

2022-08-22 16:40:09.574  INFO 17264 --- [           main] com.shrikant.config.BatchConfig          : multiResourceItemReader() execution completed

2022-08-22 16:40:09.576  INFO 17264 --- [           main] com.shrikant.config.BatchConfig          : writer() execution started

2022-08-22 16:40:09.579  INFO 17264 --- [           main] com.shrikant.config.BatchConfig          : writer() execution completed

2022-08-22 16:40:10.299  INFO 17264 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''

2022-08-22 16:40:10.313  INFO 17264 --- [           main] c.s.SpringBatchMultipleCsvToApplication  : Started SpringBatchMultipleCsvToApplication in 5.205 seconds (JVM running for 6.176)

2022-08-22 16:40:10.316  INFO 17264 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherApplicationRunner   : Running default command line with: []

2022-08-22 16:40:10.317  WARN 17264 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.a.DefaultBatchConfigurer       : No datasource was provided...using a Map based JobRepository

2022-08-22 16:40:10.318  WARN 17264 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.a.DefaultBatchConfigurer       : No transaction manager was provided, using a ResourcelessTransactionManager

2022-08-22 16:40:10.339  INFO 17264 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.

2022-08-22 16:40:10.393  INFO 17264 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=process-student]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}]

2022-08-22 16:40:10.612  INFO 17264 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [get-student]

2022-08-22 16:40:10.894  INFO 17264 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [get-student] executed in 282ms

2022-08-22 16:40:10.907  INFO 17264 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=process-student]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 344ms
```

When I run this code, I don't get error, but I don't see the data in output/user.csv file
I don't what's wrong, can anyone help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Is the application logging the creation of the beans? Is `BatchConfig` In the same package or subpackage of `@SpringBootApplication`? Are the resources correctly loaded?

Comment: BatchConfig is in the different package.

Comment: Put `BatchConfig` In the same package or subpackage of the `@SprngBootApplication`. Otherwise you have to put `@ComponentScan` on the `@SpringBootApplication` in order to tell spring witch package to scan for beans. By default it scans only package or subpackage of the `@SpringBootApplication`

Comment: @Pp88 I tried that, still same error

Comment: Do you see the logs you have putted in the configuration class in the console? Do you have any error or nothing at all? Put the package name in the answer if you can

Comment: It runs put a log when you construct `MultiResourceItemReader` to see if the resources are empty. Also you are depending on `spring-boot-starter-web` That starts the embedded tomcat. I think you don’t want that for a batch

Comment: @Pp88 I don't know how to do that, actually never use logger, I only used this beacuase it was not working and to debug it, can you tell see the resources ?

Comment: `log.info(“resources:  {}, resources is empty: {}”, resources , resources.length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the writer you have to use `new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/output/user.csv")` instead of `new ClassPathResource("output/user.csv")`. With this you also don't have to worry to create the file first, it will create it if not exists.

```
 @Bean
 public FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer(){
    log.info("writer() execution started");
    FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/output/user.csv"));
    writer.setAppendAllowed(true);
    DelimitedLineAggregator<User> delimitedLineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
    delimitedLineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
    BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<User> beanWrapperFieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
    beanWrapperFieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] {"id","name","department","salary"});
    delimitedLineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(beanWrapperFieldExtractor);
    writer.setLineAggregator(delimitedLineAggregator);
    log.info("writer() execution completed");
    return writer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its working now. But I didn't understand why it is not working ClassPathResource("").

Comment: From what I’ve read `ClassPathResource` Should be used only to retrieve resources already present in the classpath. Onestly I don’t know why spring-boot doesn’t throw any exception

Comment: Ohh. also when I try to change my model's (User) id type to int I get error I have updated the question above with logs2, actually I have the requirement of type int for model's id, I was getting this error earlier that's why I temporarily changed it to String to make it work. Can you see what's causing this problem ?

Comment: I think you should ask another question.  Please remove logs2 from the question it will confuse other people. Please if you ask another question add all the relevant details for example adding the csv input files you are using.

Comment: okay.. I didn't thought of that...

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73449719/failed-to-convert-property-value-of-type-java-lang-string-to-required-type-i   I have posted my question here