# [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'id' spring batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to read data from multiple csv file present in resources/input/user_*.csv and writing in one csv file present in resources/output/user.csv

This is my BatchConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Value(value = "classpath:input/user_*.csv")
    private Resource[] resources;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<User> flatFileItemReader(){
        log.info("flatFileItemReader execution started");
        FlatFileItemReader<User> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setName("ReadMultipleCsv");
        reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        log.info("flatFileItemReader execution completed");
        return reader;
    }

    private LineMapper<User> lineMapper(){
        DefaultLineMapper<User> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);
        lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"id","name","department","salary"});

        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<User> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(User.class);

        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
        return lineMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public MultiResourceItemReader<User> multiResourceItemReader(){
        log.info("multiResourceItemReader() execution started");
        MultiResourceItemReader<User> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
        reader.setResources(resources);
        reader.setDelegate(flatFileItemReader());
        log.info("multiResourceItemReader() execution completed");
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer(){
        log.info("writer() execution started");
        FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        writer.setResource(new ClassPathResource("output/user.csv"));
        writer.setAppendAllowed(true);

        DelimitedLineAggregator<User> delimitedLineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
        delimitedLineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<User> beanWrapperFieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        beanWrapperFieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] {"id","name","department","salary"});
        delimitedLineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(beanWrapperFieldExtractor);
        writer.setLineAggregator(delimitedLineAggregator);
        log.info("writer() execution completed");
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step(){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("get-student").<User, User>chunk(5)
                .reader(multiResourceItemReader())
                .writer(writer()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(){
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("process-student").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step()).end().build();
    }
}
```

And this is my User model

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String department;
    private String salary;
}
```

I have a requirement of the User's id of type int, but when I try run this above code it's throwing below error

```
org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 8 in resource=[file [C:\Users\NavghS\Downloads\spring-batch-multiple-csv-to\spring-batch-multiple-csv-to\target\classes\input\user_1.csv]], input=[]

               at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:189) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:93) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader.readFromDelegate(MultiResourceItemReader.java:143) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader.readNextItem(MultiResourceItemReader.java:122) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader.read(MultiResourceItemReader.java:111) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:99) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:180) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:126) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:118) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:71) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]

               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]

               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]

               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]

               at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

               at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

               at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

               at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

               at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]

               at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]

               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:199) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]

               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]

               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]

               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]

               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]

               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]

               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]

               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]

               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]

               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]

               at com.shrikant.SpringBatchMultipleCsvToApplication.main(SpringBatchMultipleCsvToApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]

Caused by: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors

Field error in object 'target' on field 'id': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.target.id,typeMismatch.id,typeMismatch.int,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [target.id,id]; arguments []; default message [id]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'id'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""]

               at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.mapFieldSet(BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.java:201) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper.mapLine(DefaultLineMapper.java:43) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:185) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

               ... 54 common frames omitted

 

2022-08-22 23:12:54.207  INFO 13816 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [get-student] executed in 81ms

2022-08-22 23:12:54.234  INFO 13816 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=process-student]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [FAILED] in 149ms
```

I am using these two files

```
1,bill,IT,12000
2,john,HR,10000
3,steve,IT,12000
4,reek,IT,12000
5,robb,HR,10000
6,don,IT,12000
7,karim,IT,12000

1,josh,IT,12000
2,sansa,HR,10000
3,roger,IT,12000
4,arya,IT,12000
5,walter,HR,10000
6,jessy,IT,12000
7,messi,IT,12000
```

Can anyone see what's the causing this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the csv of input you are using

Comment: check your input files. At line 8 there is a line with spaces. The file must not contain spaces at the end

Answer (score 1):

There is space in line number 8, that's why you are getting error. Please remove that and try.